# org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize

Tags: soap, httpwebrequest, soapui, apex-code

i am trying to call service by passing xml request. but i am getting error in response xml. Can you please help in this problem. I am using soapUI and i have set credential in request header. Response :  soapenv:Server.userException org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you're sending it an element it's not expecting, i.e. your request is invalid for some reason. Check it with a lint tool to ensure it's valid, then double check the spec for the service you're making the request to.

Failing that, you'll need to provide a lot more information to get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks 4 the response...

Actually i am trying to pass xml within WDSL definition. Please see below soap request : 

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:man="http://eapisws.cbp.dhs.gov/ws/manifest1_0/">
<soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <man:manifest>Here i am passing xml</man:manifest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

I met the same exception, for me , the reason is the wrong returnType, my returnType was set by String when I called, but the real returnType is document, my way to resolve this problem is like the following:

```
call.setReturnType(org.apache.axis.encoding.XMLType.SOAP_STRING);
```

Change to

```
call.setReturnType(org.apache.axis.encoding.XMLType.SOAP_DOCUMENT);
```